# Charging a card in Stripe using java

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm new at Stripe integration and java too and the first thing I want to do is charging a credit card. I'm using java. Here is the code for charging the card.

```
enter code here
 //CHARGING THE CARD

Stripe.apiKey = "cgchhcchv";
// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
String token = request.getParameter("stripeToken");

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chargeParams.put("amount", 1000); // amount in cents, again
chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
chargeParams.put("source", token);
chargeParams.put("description", "Example charge");

Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
} catch (CardException e) {
// The card has been declined
}
```

I added the Stripe libraries and they seem to work well but when trying to execute this code these errors output: "HashMap cannot be resolved to a type", "request cannot be resolved". I don't understand why these errors output even when I create these variables that cannot be resolved.Can someone explain this? Regards!

Comment: You need to include those classes in your code if you want to use them. Something like `import java.util.HashMap;` at the top of your file to be able to use HashMap for example

Comment: Thanks it works. What about request var?

Comment: I guess you need a package that will allow you to retrieve the POST parameters from the request. There are numerous packages that can do that for you in Java depending on the way you built your integration. For example: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @Doe try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557120/stripe-integration-in-android-and-create-token/30186418#30186418

Answer (score 1):

In the github release page you can find several examples:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.stripe.Stripe;
import com.stripe.exception.StripeException;
import com.stripe.model.Charge;
import com.stripe.net.RequestOptions;
```